# variable key name

Tags: php, key

Can I check for a variable key without using a temporary variable.

```
$var = 'blabla';
$key = "{$var}_abc";

if(isset($someobject->$key))...
```

?

with arrays you can do this... $array["{$var}_abc"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use curly braces containing an expression resulting in a string, where that string is the name of the property you want to check.

```
$someobject->{"{$var}_abc"}
$someobject->{$var."_abc"}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use concatenation like `$array[$var."_abc"]`

Answer (score 1):

yes, try enclosing the variable in braces

Edit: not paranthesis, braces..

Answer (score 1):

You can employ braces around the member name:

```
if (isset($someobject->{$var.'_abc'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, using [property_exists()](http://php.net/property_exists) method

```
if(property_exists($object, $var."_abc")) {
 // do stuff
}
```